# Uitableview shift down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've two tableviews side by side, I use below code to make them scroll like one table when I scroll on either of the two tables.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.coinNameTableView {
        self.coinInfoTableView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: false)
    }
    if scrollView == self.coinInfoTableView {
        self.coinNameTableView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: false)
    }
}
```

But there is one issue, when the first cell is at the begin of the table, then I scroll down, the whole table will shift down and not bounce back to the original location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `scrollViewDidScroll` method, write logic for `content offset`. If content offset is less than 0, than set the content offset == 0.

Reference code:-

```
if scrollView.ContentOffset.y < 0{
self.coinInfoTableView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)

self.coinNameTableView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)

}
```